# Yii criteria selecting all rows

Tags: php, yii, conditional-statements

I am useing Yii framework to do a criteria selection for all rows that fit the criteria.
I am trying to take the ID of one table and search another tables codes that contain the prefix of the ID. (exp ID-code or 1-sdfa).  Currently the code below is returning all of the rows as a result.  Below are the details, any insight would help. Thank you.

```
[table 1]
tbl_School
---------------------------
| ID |       Name         |
---------------------------
| 1  |   forist hills     |
| 2  |       Dhs          |
---------------------------
```

```
[table 2]
tbl_ticket
------------------
| ID |   code    |
------------------
| 1  |  1-fd23s  |
| 2  |  2-fdet2  |
| 3  |  1-4wscd  |
| 4  |  2-oifjd  |
| 5  |  1-zzds6  |
------------------
```

After runing the function on ID=1 I would like to see

```
------------------
| ID |   code    |
------------------
| 1  |  1-fd23s  |
| 3  |  1-4wscd  |
| 5  |  1-zzds6  | 
------------------
```

Here is my code:

```
public static function get_tickets($ticket_ID){
$match = '';
$match = addcslashes($match, "$ticket_ID".'_%');
$q = new CDbCriteria( array(
'condition' => "code LIKE :match",
'params'    => array(':match' => "$match%")
) );

$rows = Ticket::model()->findAll( $q );    
return $rows;

}
```

Comment: try change like `addcslashes($match, "$ticket_ID".'-%');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO does escaping for you so you don't need to do the `addcslashes` yourself (I didn't even know that existed, always used `addslashes` :) )

Secondly, you end up selecting on `[NUMBER]_%%`, those are 3 wildcards. 
As Ryan already changed in its comment, you might want to select on -% instead:

```
public static function get_tickets($ticket_ID){
   $ticket_ID = intval($ticket_ID);
   if (!$ticket_ID)
      return null;

   $q = new CDbCriteria( array(
      'condition' => "code LIKE :match",
      'params'    => array(':match' => $ticket_ID . "-%")
   ) );

   $rows = Ticket::model()->findAll( $q );    
   return $rows;
}
```

As you can see, I did do a numeric sanity check for the ticket number, just like being cautious.

Lastly: I hope you don't mind the suggestion, but isn't it simply possible adding the ticket number as a separate column? You are going to end up with perfectly avoidable performance problems if there are a lot of rows in this table. With a separate column that is an index you'd use a lot less cpu for the same result.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, and Blizz, it works perfectly.  Blizz as for a separate column, this is an option that I do have on the table, however the code has to stay the same with the [schoolID-code] so adding another column of schoolID may be redundant, and I don't think the performance will be too much.  If I do have issues with this later, this will be the first thing I change.  Thank you

Comment: If I wanted to order by ID DESC, would i just add another condition?

Comment: $q->order = 'ID DESC'; obviously before you call `findAll()` :) (or add an 'order' => 'ID DESC' to the `new` call)